# General strategies for entrepreneurs with many projects

Tags: entrepreneurship

I was wondering if there is a recognized situation in the field of entrepreneurship where instead of a person having one specific idea they are banking on, an entrepreneur is a generally creative person who enjoys designing, planning and orchestrating projects but they have a wide variety of possible projects to work on.

I think this is valid and realistic, for example, Elon Musk has had to step back from some companies he founded because he did not have time for them on top of newer projects.

However, I am picturing an up-and-coming entrepreneur who has many ideas and enjoys working on them presenting a catalogue of possible projects and seeing which people and investors find appealing to themselves. I think it makes a lot of sense, just like designers have lots of sample designs; also, it lets you see which of your ideas are more well-received.

Comment: I don't think I would want to invest in someone with 50 ideas on the go, even if the one I like is moderately developed for the exact reason you already point out - Elon had to step back from some of them because he did not have time. What if the project you decided to step back from, is the one I invested in?

Comment: _"Elon Musk has had to step back from some companies he founded because he did not have time for them"_ ..nor the necessary and specific expertise -> see twitter, spaceX etc..

Comment: This seems to be a rather fantasy-like characterisation of entrepreneurship.

Answer (score 4):

What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

If you are doing market research to determine what sort of business you might want to open, it's very reasonable to be testing multiple ideas at the same time (though generally not on the same set of people).  If no one seems interested in your idea of a subscription service that delivers you fresh toast every morning that's useful to know before you mortgage your house to start the company.

If you are trying to attract investment, however, it's probably a bad plan.  Investors want to invest in companies not ideas.  They want to see your financials and to see what sort of revenue and profit you've been able to produce.  They want to see that you're committed to this particular business.  Getting a business to the point where you have financial results is expensive both in terms of time and money so it is unlikely that most people could get more than one business to that state.  Someone like Elon Musk is very much an outlier in that regard.  If you're a serial entrepreneur that has accumulated millions (or billions) from prior successful projects, it is a lot easier to get a new venture off the ground-- writing 8 figure checks tends to solve a lot of problems.  But if you're just starting out and don't have a track record of enviable investment returns, you're unlikely to attract investments from anyone other than friends and family.

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on what you are wanting to sell.

If you are wanting to sell the businesses that make those projects, that is a very expensive proposition as each business needs to be funded and built.

If you are wanting to sell the projects to different businesses, that is a different proposition. You will need to find how to present the project to different businesses. There was a company that attempted to do that and was full of different projects. It went under as it was generating projects far faster than it could sell them. (From my experience in selling art, I would suspect that attempting this would require that you invest 50% of your time on marketing.)

If you want to sell your ability to create projects, then all you need is to build each project to a Minimal Viable Project. Put them on your resume and go out to find a company that might value you for that capability. However, few companies will bring in someone like that and use them right away. Internal politics become the limiting factor in most cases. Creative people rarely fit into corporate politics.

Finally, you might seek employment as an outside creative consultant. In such a role, you bring creative ideas to your clients. They take your ideas and run. You might also sell the process of creativity.

Answer (score 1):

From an investing standpoint, nothing is more risky than investing in an idea. Business' within their first few years are still exceedingly risky from an investment standpoint. I would not expect most investors to bite at a single idea, let alone a portfolio of them. That's just too much risk and too much work.

What you are describing would be a dream job for a lot of people. Idea inception is incredibly enjoyable. Building a business is borderline torture.

Now that all of the negativity is out of the way, some possible ways that this could work out. Consulting comes to mind since that would allow you the freedom to jump from project to project with relative ease and minimal professional friction. This could take the form of actually doing early market research for others or building their minimal viable products for them. To get started, moving your initial ideas to the point of minimal viable product or business proposal would be useful.

A lot of this depends on whether or not you need an income from your explorations. As with all things like this, make sure to build up your portfolio and options before taking that leap.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible with enough marketing skill.

Generally though you need a good reputation before you start selling pie in the sky. In your case you must have many completed projects under your belt already, so utilise that network for more work.